# Entity Framework : How to generate a migration to change a foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a foreign key constraint in a migration that looks like this :

```
table.ForeignKey(
name: "FK_GameConditionCombinations_GameConditions_GameCondition1Id",
column: x => x.GameCondition1Id,
principalTable: "GameConditions",
principalColumn: "GameConditionId",
onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

However, many migrations later I would like to change the onDelete to ReferentialAction.NoAction. Is it possible to do this without having to rollback dozens of migrations in order to change this one? How would I create a new migration to specifically change this foreign key constraint, is it possible to generate a new migration or would I need (or can I) create a new migration manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your modelbuilder config for entity GameConditionCombination as below :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GameConditionCombination>()
    .HasOne(gcc => gcc.GameCondition1)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(gcc => gcc.GameCondition1Id)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Now you can add new migration to fix your issue.